# ASP.NET Ajax 4 and Microsoft Ajax library definitions

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

I undestand that is former for Web Forms ASP.Net only , latter ( currently preview 6 ) suitable for both - classic and MVC. Would it be possible to give a brief description/usage for each. 
By ASP.NET Ajax 4  I meant what is described in the following article

Data Binding in ASP.NET AJAX 4.0

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ee309508.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Asp.Net Ajax was renamed to Microsoft Ajax lately.

No, regarding the client-side library, both can be used in MVC. The clinet-side library is just javascript files, you can use it even in PHP, Rails, JSP.

If you are talking about server-side components like UpdatePanel,etc.. Yes, they can only be used in WebForm environment.

Hope this makes sense.